# Chat Application With AMS.Web.RemoteScripting.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am planning to develop chat application in ASP.Net and learn from codeproject about AMS.Web.RemoteScripting.dll. I have tried to download it but the source doesn't allow me to download as per their system.

Is there anybody know where the AMS.Web.RemoteScripting.dll can download free?.

OR

Any better Idea for developing chat application in asp.net c#-2005

Comment: I do not know of any realtime server running .NET 2.0. But if you can host the server on 4.0 (somewhere) XSockets.NET has a .NET 2.0 client that you can use to build a chat very easy... But if you do not have the possibility to host on 4.0 you have to look else where for a solution

Comment: @Uffe, Thanks I will try your suggestion.......

Comment: Ok. Join the forum http://xsockets.net/developer-forum or send an email to contact@xsockets.net and you will get info about the 2.0 client

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest and probably the best way to develop an asp.net chat application is to use SignalR.

Comment: SignalR not supported to VS-2005